# Swift screenshot function sometimes returning blank UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext

I have the following code, which I have been using to generate screenshots of UIViews.  Here are some details about when it works and and when it doesn't:

---

**When it works:**

1) UIView is built completely in Swift (i.e., not built in Interface Builder)

2) Superview of UIView is another UIView

---

**When it doesn't work:**

1) UIView is built in Interface Builder

2) Superview of UIView is UIScrollView

3) I know I'm getting images returned and successfully added back to the superview because I'm printing each returned image and also printing the subviews of the superview after calling the function and the images and subviews match.

---

I've tried calling the function in viewDidLoad and also in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  In either case, it is the last function being called when loading the view.

```
func pictureTaker(_ rawView: UIView) -> UIImageView {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rawView.bounds.size, false, 0)
    rawView.drawHierarchy(in: rawView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    let viewImage = UIImageView(image: screenshot)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    viewImage.frame = rawView.frame
    return viewImage
}
```

Comment: call above function after view didapper's, in viewdidload frames of view not aligned properly

Comment: Wow, what an easy fix - that worked.  I thought that viewDidLayoutSubviews was the last function to get called on startup.  Thanks!